# Issue fetch lat and long from the given address in android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geocode, httpconnection

I am getting problem of getting latitude and longitude from the google url as shown below and i am using asynctask,no problem of network.i have address array which has 4 adderesses and i am using like below:

```
for(int i = 0; i < address.length; ++i) {
Log.e("i value: ",i+"");
try {
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address[i] + "&sensor=false");
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
.......   //codes to get lat and long
.......
} catch(......) {
 }
}
```

As you can see i print the i value using Log.It is coming as 0,1,2,3,but it is calling this url for first time only i.e. for i value 0 and getting the lat and long of that address but not for the next 3 values.Any help ? thanks

Comment: Do you have catch clause empty?

Comment: @MaciejGórski yes empty.u want me to print stacktrace ?

Comment: This way you will find your coding error easily. Never leave catch empty. Always do at least Log.e, even though it's the worst way to handle IO error in production code.